# Apache httpclient does not exist. Error

Tags: java, apache, compilation

Hi I keep getting an errors
[image]

```
test.java:15: package org.apache.commons.httpclient does not exist
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie;
                                ^
test.java:16: package org.apache.commons.httpclient does not exist
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState;
                                ^
test.java:17: package org.apache.commons.httpclient does not exist
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
                                ^
test.java:18: package org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods does not exist
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
                                        ^
test.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpClient
location: class test
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            ^
test.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpClient
location: class test
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                                    ^
test.java:26: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GetMethod
location: class test
            GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://online.investools.com/authentication/auth.iedu");
            ^
test.java:26: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GetMethod
location: class test
            GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://online.investools.com/authentication/auth.iedu");
                                   ^
test.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Cookie
location: class test
                              Cookie[] cookies = client.getState().getCookies();
                              ^
test.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Cookie
location: class test
                                    Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
                                    ^
10 errors
```

to compile I used

```
javac -cp ;./httpclient-4.2.jar;jsoup-1.6.3.jar test.java
```

and this is the code

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie;  
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState;  
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;  
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod; 


public class test{
public static void main (String []args)throws IOException{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  
    client.getParams().setParameter("username", "SomeUSER");  
    client.getParams().setParameter("password", "GF@QT#$WE");  

    GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://online.investools.com/authentication/auth.iedu");  
        try{  
              client.executeMethod(method);  
              Cookie[] cookies = client.getState().getCookies();  
              for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {  
                Cookie cookie = cookies[i];  
                System.err.println(  
                  "Cookie: " + cookie.getName() +  
                  ", Value: " + cookie.getValue() +  
                  ", IsPersistent?: " + cookie.isPersistent() +  
                  ", Expiry Date: " + cookie.getExpiryDate() +  
                  ", Comment: " + cookie.getComment());  
                }  
              client.executeMethod(method);  
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {  
          System.err.println(e);  
        } 
        finally {  
          method.releaseConnection();  
        }
```

I am very confused and don't know what I'm doing wrong. I think it is simple, but I have checked several times and it exists and jsoup compiles fine. 
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I believe you want `org.apache.http.client` if you're using [HttpClient 4.2](http://hc.apache.org/user-docs.html) (which it looks like you are). The `org.apache.commons.httpclient` package is for the [older version](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

EDIT: Not *all* the classes which were in `httpclient` are now in `http.client`; some are just in `http`. Additionally, other changes are required - for example, `HttpClient` is now an interface, so you can't instantiate it like that. Basically, you've got 3.x code, so you should either update it to 4.x or use the 3.x jar files.

Comment: <code>import org.apache.http.client.Cookie;  
    <code>import org.apache.http.client.HttpState;  
    <code>import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;  
    <code>import org.apache.http.client.methods.GetMethod;

Comment: @user1093111: "it didn't work" is hardly informative. It's possible that more work is required to convert 3.x code to 4.2, but we can't easily help you if you don't give us more information.

Comment: Sorry, its the same cannot find symbol error.  Exactly like the top. 10 errors all the same. I re-downloaded and extracted the jar file as well.

Comment: @user1093111: It looks like this code was written for 3.x, yes. Not all the classes are in `org.apache.http.client` - some are just in `org.apache.http`. Read the docs for more information.

Comment: It compiled with 3.x, then I ran it and got

'code'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.<clinit>(HttpClient.java:65)
        at test.main(test.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)

Answer (score 1):

i found my missing version from here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient

```
dependencies {
    compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
}
```

Comment: You should definitely drop 1-2 sentences and explain your solution. Just dropping code is frowned upon here. In which way does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

use jar -xvf httpclient-4.2.java temp

check if org/apache/commons/httpclient/Cookie is there, if not there it is wrong/corrupted jar

Also try javac -cp .;./httpclient-4.2.jar;jsoup-1.6.3.jar test.java instead of 
javac -cp ;./httpclient-4.2.jar;jsoup-1.6.3.jar test.java

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: httpclient-4.2.java (The system cannot find the file specified) when using jar -xvf httpclient-4.2.java temp